# Mysql запрос. Ошибка 1093

Tags: mysql

```
delete from wp_postmeta
where post_id in
(SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'spam')
```

При данном запросе появляется ошибка 1093. Подскажите как переписать запрос, чтобы запрос выполнился

Comment: строк c одним post_id 25. и только в одном из 25 meta_key = 'spam'

Answer (score 0):

```
 DELETE FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` IN (
  SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT `post_id` FROM `wp_postmeta`  WHERE `meta_value` = 'spam'
   ) AS p
  )
```